# Responder' rebid with unbalanced hand (system: Simple SAYC)

Tags: bridge, bidding

I have 1S-4H-4D-4C, 15 PTS. I open 1D -- Partner: 1S --> Now my options are:

- I can't bid 1NT (no nt distribution).
- I want to show that I have more than minimum (12-14 pts), so I don't want to bid 2C, so I bid 3C. Is my reasoning correct?

Answer (score 3):

In a word, no. A jump shift shows a game forcing hand (something like 18 HCP with that distribution). 2C could be any strength that's not game forcing across from a minimum responder, and is probably your best bid here.

Comment: Probably? Undoubtedly! 2C describes the hand as best as a second bid can.

Answer (score 3):

Agreed with Ruds; absolutely do not, under any conditions, bid anything other than 2C with the hand described..

It is important to realize that partner with 10+ support points can be expected to make a game invitation, or reveal the pending misfit by either a simple preference to 2D or a rebid of spades. Your responsibility is to describe your hand, which the simple rebid of 2C does perfectly.